# reset form value/object to empty upon ng-click in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-ngmodel, angular-controller

Description:
I'm using ui-router to load form pages upon icon click, whenever the user clicks the icon the new form should load ( remove any filled fields ). I have added ng-click on icon which can be leveraged to reset the form values.

index.html

```
<td>
    <a  ui-sref="form2"
    title="yahoo">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file" ng-click="newForm('new')" id="yahooIcon" ></span>
    </a>
</td>
```

form2.html

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="myModel.firstname"><br>
```

app.js

```
$scope.newForm = function (id){
if ( id == 'new' )
  {
   console.log(" model value inside: "+$scope.myModel.firstname);   
   $scope.myModel = {};
  }
}
```

Problem:

1. ng-model data is showing undefined in controller and not able to reset the model upon clicking the icon.
2. The demo uses the same controller, However if my from has different controllers than index page. How can i send button click (ng-click) value to child controllers ?

**DEMO** ( [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b3pT87?p=preview) )

Comment: if you want to use code in multiple controllers you its time to begin thinking about services or factories, and injecting into the controllers where you need to

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This

```
//In Html Page
<button type="reset" ng-click="resetForm(formObject)">Clear Form</button>

//In Angular
$scope.resetForm = function(form) {
      angular.copy({},form);
    }
```